# CSS container goes outside parent container and is also ofsett

Tags: html, css

i am currently working on a cs go betting site, i bought the source so i am not verry familiar with it, and my css and html skills are not the greatest, but i have a problem, as you can see from the picture below the container that shows the winner is ofsett from the main container.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3n4P.png]

Here is the css code of that container:

The actual class of the container is the one named "winner-left"

```
 .winner {

    background: #737373;

    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #3c3c3c;
    padding: 12px 19px 12px 27px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;


}
.winner:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: -21px;
    background: #696969;
    border: 1px solid #898989;
    box-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #202020, 1px -1px 0 #202020;
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    z-index: 3;
}
.winner:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: -30px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 4;
    background: #6e6e6e;
}
.winner-left {
    float: left;
    position: left;
    width: 100%;

}
```

I would REALLY apreciate some help! And if more code or info is needed, just ask me!

```
div class="game-info gameend hidden">
    <div class="game-status"><strong>Game #<span class="game-num">99</span> - Over!</strong></div>
    <div class="all-players">
        <div class="all-players-list" style="-moz-transform: translate3d(390px, 0, 0);-ms-transform: translate3d(390px, 0, 0);-o-transform: translate3d(390px, 0, 0);-webkit-transform: translate3d(390px, 0, 0);transform: translate3d(390px, 0, 0); -moz-transition: 13s ease;-o-transition: 13s ease;-webkit-transition: 13s ease;transition: 13s ease; backface-visibility: hidden;">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="winner">
        <div class="winner-left">
            <h3>Last Winner <span id="winner-end">  </span></h3>
            <div class="winner-cost">
                <span class="winner-cost-title">Won:</span>
                <span class="winner-cost-value">~ 100.0</span>
                <span class="winner-cost-valuta"> $.</span>
            </div>
            <p>Prize will be sent through steam trade offer</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Add the HTML please of create a JSFiddle

Comment: So what do you want it to be like? No offset?

Comment: Try adding `position : relative;` to `.winner-left`. There are thousands of possibilites all depending on where you want that div to be.

Comment: And yes, exactly, i want no offset